# SQLite foreign key?

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables: `A` and `B`. `A` has a foreign key to `B` and `B` has a foreign key to `A`. But I cannot make a foreign key from `A` to `B`, because `A` is created before `B`.

How can I solve it when SQLite doesn't support `Alter Table`?

This is my sample database:

```
Create Table A(
  A_ID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  B_ID    INTEGER,
  A_DESCRIPTION    TEXT,

  FOREIGN KEY (B_ID) REFERENCES B(B_ID)
)

Create Table B(
  B_ID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  A_ID    INTEGER,
  B_DESCRIPTION    TEXT,

  FOREIGN KEY (A_ID) REFERENCES A(A_ID)
)
```

Answer (score 10):

You have a syntax error: there is a comma missing before `FOREIGN KEY` in table `B`.

Otherwise, your schema is correct.
(SQLite will interpret the `REFERENCES` clauses only when needed, so there is no problem creating a reference to a table that does not yet exist.)

Please note that inserting records will be problematic, unless you insert records with `NULL` values first and update them later when the referenced record exists.
It might be a better idea to create [deferred foreign key constraints](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_deferred).

Comment: Corrected the missing comma.

Answer (score 5):

I believe your issue is actually how you are defining your foreign keys. Defining circular foreign keys works just fine for me. Try this query instead:

```
pragma foreign_keys=on; 

Create Table A(
  A_ID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  B_ID    INTEGER REFERENCES B(B_ID),
  A_DESCRIPTION    TEXT
);


Create Table B(
  B_ID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  A_ID    INTEGER REFERENCES A(A_ID),
  B_DESCRIPTION    TEXT
);
```

Comment: but in this case, when table 'A' is created, table 'B' doesn't exist.. how can it make ref to B_ID??

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite **does** support `ALTER TABLE`, but in a limited capacity.

From the documentation (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) :

> The `ALTER TABLE` command in SQLite allows the user to rename a table or
>   to add a new column to an existing table. It is not possible to rename
>   a column, remove a column, or add or remove constraints from a table.

Since you aren't using constraints to your foreign keys, you could create both tables first and then add the foreign keys later with an `ALTER TABLE ADD` query, which is one of the few alter table commands that comes with SQLite.

```
CREATE TABLE A(
  ID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  A_DESCRIPTION    TEXT
)

CREATE TABLE B(
  ID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  B_DESCRIPTION    TEXT
)

ALTER TABLE A ADD FOREIGN KEY B_ID B(ID)
ALTER TABLE B ADD FOREIGN KEY A_ID A(ID)
```

If you need to add constraints to your table, [this question over here covers it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884818/how-do-i-add-a-foreign-key-to-an-existing-sqlite-3-6-21-table)

Answer (score 1):

I believe I done it before by creating tables in a transaction.