# Laravel Schema onDelete set null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

Can't figure out how to set the proper onDelete constraint on a table in Laravel. (I'm working with SQLite)

```
$table->...->onDelete('cascade'); // works
$table->...->onDelete('null || set null'); // neither of them work
```

I have 3 migrations, creating the gallery table:

```
Schema::create('galleries', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->text('path')->unique();
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
});
```

Creating the pictures table:

```
Schema::create('pictures', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('path');
    $table->string('title')->nullable();
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
    $table->integer('gallery_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('gallery_id')
        ->references('id')->on('galleries')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
});
```

Linking gallery table to a picture:

```
Schema::table('galleries', function($table)
{
    // id of a picture that is used as cover for a gallery
    $table->integer('picture_id')->after('description')
        ->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('picture_id')
        ->references('id')->on('pictures')
        ->onDelete('cascade || set null || null'); // neither of them works
});
```

I do not receive any errors. Also, even the "cascade" option doesn't work (only on the gallery table). Deleting a gallery deletes all pictures. But deleting the cover picture, wont delete the gallery (for test purposes).

Since even the "cascade" is not triggered, I "set null" is not the problem.

**EDIT (workaround):**

After reading this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38655/Prevent-Circular-References-in-Database-Design) I've changed my schema a bit. Now, the pictures table contains an "is_cover" cell, that indicates whether this picture is a cover on its album or not.

A solution to the original problem is still highly appreciated!

Answer (score 430, accepted):

If you want to set null on delete:

```
$table->...->onDelete('set null');
```

First make sure you set the foreign key field as nullable:

```
$table->integer('foreign_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

Comment: plus for `->nullable()`

Comment: Is there some Laravel documentation o this?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints it doesn't document what options there are, but I think you can assume it's the default mysql values (see
`../ vendor / laravel / framework / src / Illuminate / Database / Schema / Grammars / Grammar.php`)

Answer (score 42):

#### In laravel 7 and 8 you can use:

```
$table->foreignId('foreign_id')->nullable()->constrained("table_name")->cascadeOnUpdate()->nullOnDelete();
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

The different options are declared in the class `Illuminate\Database\Schema\ForeignKeyDefinition` ([see source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/ForeignKeyDefinition.php)).

Comment: Tested with Laravel 7, also works there.

Comment: Order matters! In case anyone (like me) places 'nullable()' after 'constrained()' you'll get the following error: "General error: 1830 Column 'foreign_id' cannot be NOT NULL..."
Just make sure that nullable is called before constrained!

Answer (score 6):

According to

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

$table->onDelete('set null') should work prehaps try

```
$table->...->onDelete(DB::raw('set null'));
```

If there are any errors, would also be helpful

Comment: You might want to roll back, write out the sql by hand and then execture and run tests on local. Everything I can find says that should work http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html, could be an issue generating the sql

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it resulted in the same issue. I think it's something specific to SqLite and circular references.

Comment: Plus one because onDelete('set null') works with mysql.

Answer (score 6):

- <s>This is a known issue in Laravel. More info about this [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/771).</s>
- This feature is not supported in SQLite, see [here](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html)
- Also a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884818/how-do-i-add-a-foreign-key-to-an-existing-sqlite-3-6-21-table/1884841#1884841) that has a detailed showdown of this problem

Comment: @SimonBengtsson The issue must have been closed or deleted.

Answer (score 4):

in laravel 8 you can do it like this.

```
 $table->foreignId('table_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('set null');
```

nullable() column modifiers must be called before constrained() and onDelete('set null')

Answer (score 3):

Using Laravel 4.2 on MySQL 5.5 with InnoDB, onDelete('set null') works.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `nullOnDelete()` method as well. See laravel 8.x https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

```
$table->foreignId('table_id')->nullable()->constrained()->nullOnDelete();
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't support the ADD CONSTRAINT variant of the ALTER TABLE command

[SQLite foreign key dont set null on delete in phpunit test](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/sqlite-foreign-key-dont-set-null-on-delete-in-phpunit-test)