# I have tables: categories & items table which has a foreign key of $category_id. How can I delete a category and make f-key nullable on items table?

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, crud, laravel-livewire

I can't delete a category because it is a foreign key in the items table. How can I do it? How can I make a deletion in category and make $category_id null in the items table?

I tried making a delete function but it sends an error saying it can't because it is a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

Create a migration to allow the field `category_id` to have null value and to default to null when the referenced category is deleted by setting onDelete null on foreign key

```
$table->foreignId('category_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('set null');
```

[You can also read from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869072/laravel-schema-ondelete-set-null)

[Official Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Answer (score -1):

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
// write your delete code here
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

Comment: Please don't just dump two lines of code as an answer! Add some explanation of why that code would work etc. so others can learn. Thanks

Comment: Sorry. It will disable foreign key constrain for the code inside the block.

public function deleteCategory(Category $category){
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
$categoru->delete();
//Now you can enable the foreign key  constrain
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');

}

Comment: at the expense of database integrity. You will end up with entries referencing categories that doesn't exist and create more bugs down the line. and now even if there is a category_id value in the entry you need to check for its existance in the categories table. good job, you're making your life harder.

Comment: You can write the logic for that inside your function.
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');

It will enable the foreign key to constrain again.

If a product can't exist without a category then you should delete the product too.

Or you can set the category_id to 0. Your problem was due to constraining you are not unable to delete. Thats what I have suggested this path but you have to think the logic yourself

Comment: The explanation belongs in your answer, not buried in comments. Edit your answer to add information.