# Is it possible to change a column without run raw sql in DbVisualizer + SQLite

Tags: sqlite, dbvisualizer, sqlitemanager

Working on a SQLite database, seems DbVisualizer Pro does a lot of work very well, except one,

**Changing table schema.**

I **often** need to change column name, data type, etc, but don't want to do it through raw SQL statement. My workaround is opening Firefox's SQLite Manager to just change the schema.

[image]

Is it possible to use DbVisualizer to change the schema? many thanks!

**Edit:**
Alter table action mentioned [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34671898/2055187) by roger, seems to be the right way to go. But somehow I can only add column, the existing column appears to be read only.

[image]

Mine is DBVisualizer Pro **Evaluation**. Is non-Evaluation different?

[image]

**Edit2**:
Using SQLite Manager is **sometimes** dangerous, as warned below. just learned, renaming a column may cause the foreign key loss. but workaround is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28399551/2055187)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In DbVisualizer Pro there is the [Alter Table](http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG92/Altering+a+Table) action (and Create Table for creating new tables). Select the actual table you want to change in the **Databases** tab, right-click and chose **Alter Table**. In order for this to work you need DbVisualizer Pro and the **Database Type** for your connection must be set to either **Auto Detect** (recommended) or **SQLite**.

Comment: Renaming columns are not supported by SQLite and that is why the names are read-only in DbVisualizer.