# How to create a relation with a defaule value between two existing tables?

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys, relationship, alter-table

I have two existing tables, workTable and table_jobs. I want to update my workTable and create a relationship with table_jobs with a default value. This is what I tried:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    switch (oldVersion){
        case 3:{

            int jobid = insertJobWithoutClosing(new Job("Default", Color.rgb(0, 0, 255)), db);
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + workTable + " ADD COLUMN " + colJobID + " INTEGER DEFAULT " + jobid + " FOREIGN KEY("+colJobID+") REFERENCES "+table_jobs+"("+job_ID+")");

        }

    }
```

This gives me the following exception:

> > android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FOREIGN": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE WorkObjects ADD COLUMN JobID INTEGER DEFAULT 1 FOREIGN KEY(JobID) REFERENCES Jobs(jobsID)

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FOREIGN KEY clause is a table constraint.
ALTER TABLE does not support table constraints.

You have to make the foreign key constraint a column constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE WorkObjects
ADD COLUMN JobID INTEGER DEFAULT 1 REFERENCES Jobs(jobsID);
```

```
Error: Cannot add a REFERENCES column with non-NULL default value
```

Oh well. You have to recreate the table.

Answer (score 0):

[Here there is a well explained answer for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884818/how-do-i-add-a-foreign-key-to-an-existing-sqlite-3-6-21-table) It seems foreign keys can be added only when you create the table. You can move your data in a new temp table, then recreate your original one with the foreign key constraint.