# In Laravel, SQLite Foreign Keys with Set Null on Delete not working for PHPUnit test

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I have added a foreign keys constraint in migration file for posts table to the user_id column. So, on delete user, I want to set the user_id column to null. So, I added this.

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('users')
      ->onDelete('set null');
```

It is working on the MySQL database. But not working on SQLite PHPUnit test. I have enabled foreign key constraints for SQLite, but still not working.

Please guide How can I make it work?

Comment: did you add this migration in `alter` or `create` table?

Comment: I added this in `alter` migration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a foreign key to an existing SQLite table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884818/how-do-i-add-a-foreign-key-to-an-existing-sqlite-table)