# SQLite Delete row from Table A when columns are referenced as FOREIGN KEYS in other Tables B, C, etc

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, sql-delete

So I have several tables, but will show only 2 as an example:

```
Table G

gNo | gName | gAddress
G1  | Jean  | Bonalbo
G2  | Oscar | Berlin
G3  | Edd   | Brisbane
G4  | Bob   | California

Table B

gNo | gdate | rNo
G1  | 2019  | R21
G2  | 1993  | R03
G3  | 1989  | R26
G4  | 2020  | R04
```

Now, I need to DELETE the last row from Table G, but SQLite keeps saying that there is a FOREIGN KEY  constraint failure. This is what I've done:

```
DELETE FROM G WHERE gNo = 'G4';
```

I know that's not complete. I tried using CASCADE at the end of that line, but it throws ERROR. Then I tried using `DELETE FROM G JOIN Table B WHERE gNo = 'G4';` and didn't work either.

I'm very lost here.

Some help?

Comment: What are your table definitions? The actual `CREATE TABLE` statements, added to your question.

Comment: You can't add foreign key constraints after you create a table in SQLite. You must do it when you create the tables. Check other options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884818/how-do-i-add-a-foreign-key-to-an-existing-sqlite-table

Comment: @Shawn this is a database I downloaded from a website. I don't have the sql of how it was crafted. Sorry.

Comment: @forpas Thank you, I'm going to check your link.
PS: I haven't upvoted the answers, I think the people that post the answers are upvoting them themselves. If not, I don't know what's happening, because that's not me.

Comment: `.schema` in the `sqlite3` command line shell will show you the table definitions for a database.

Comment: @EddSoul24 Users can't upvote their own posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't delete a row that is referenced by a row in another table - that's one of the features of foreign keys.

You would typically need to delete the child(ren) record(s) first:

```
delete from b where gno = 'G4';
delete from g where gno = 'G4);
```

Otherwise, you need to change the definition of the foreign key so it includes the `on delete cascade` option:

```
create table b (
    gno text references g(gno) on delete cascade,
    gdate int,
    rno text,
    ...
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought about this solution(first one about deleting the children first), but it seemed too obvious and I thought I needed to use CASCADE, UPDATE or JOIN clauses.
This worked, although I think SQLite should have a function that does this more efficiently.

About the second suggestion, the database was downloaded from a website, so I'm just trying to modify its content.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define the foreign key constraint with `cascade`.  You can delete the existing constraint and define the foreign key as:

```
create table b (
    . . .,
    gno int references g(gno) on delete cascace
);
```

This tells the database that when you delete a row in the primary table, then to delete the references as well.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=681396ae63647792ba1c782adcf8430e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: How is this question upvoted? SQLite does not support adding foreign key constraints.

Comment: @forpas . . . It is interesting then that the documentation disagrees with you:  https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html.

Comment: *The only schema altering commands directly supported by SQLite are the "rename table", "rename column", and "add column"* from https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html Where exactly did you find the documentation that disagrees with me?